# Adding subview leaves gap between subview and navigation bar

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios5

I've got a storyboard with a view wrapped in a navigationcontroller, that has a UI tab bar at the bottom.  I dynamically add sub views to this view, but there is always a blank line between the navigation bar and the subview that appears to be the width of a status bar.  On each of the subviews that are created on the storyboard I have their Simulated Metrics set to have a bottom bar as a Tab Bar, status bar is set to none, and top bar is set to navigation bar.

Below is my code for adding the sub view:

```
    if(!self.homeViewController){
         self.homeViewController = [self.storyboardinstantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeView"];        
    }

    if(self.currentViewController != self.homeViewController)
    {            
        [self.view insertSubview:self.homeViewController.view belowSubview:self.tabBar];
        [self.currentViewController removeFromParentViewController];
    }

    self.currentViewController = self.homeViewController;
```

Comment: Where are you defining the frames of these objects?

Comment: Well I define all the visual in the storyboard.

Comment: Not really.  I ended up redoing how I was creating the view.

Answer (score 0):

On your homeViewController defined in Storyboard, set the 'Resize View From NIB' property to **unticked** (this is ticked by default).  This cured the gap problem for me.