# Gap between navigation bar and subview ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, subview

I understand there is this question: [Adding subview leaves gap between subview and navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310683/adding-subview-leaves-gap-between-subview-and-navigation-bar)

However, there is no answer, and I do my method a different way, so that might make it a bit different.  Anyways, I as well have a gap between the navigation bar and subview when I add a subview to my navigation controller, which also has a tab bar controller.  I am using storyboards.  I am adding the subview using `UIViewController.view` type via storyboard id.

My code:

```
[self.view addSubview:[[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View"] view]];
```

This works, and adds the view, but with the gap above it.  Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your 'View' view controller defined in Storyboard, set the 'Resize View From NIB' property to **unticked** (this is ticked by default). This cured the gap problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by setting the `translucent` property of `UINavigationController` to `NO`. Add the following line in viewDidLoad

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```