# iOS space between placeholder view and navigation bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uitableview, uistoryboard

I have added a placeholder view to add new subview base on the selected segmented. One of the subview is an UITableViewController and this load another view when cell is selected. But when the app is push back from this third view, the UITableView is shift down a bit. I suppose this is due to new navigation bar been added to main subview. This illustrate more on following images.

I have followed this post [Gap between navigation bar and subview ios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15801365/gap-between-navigation-bar-and-subview-ios) and that didn't work for me.

[image: Before navigating to subview]
Before navigating to subview

[image: After coming back to main view]
After pushing back to main view subview

How can I get rid of this extra space? I am using the storyboard and iOS7. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's seam like there something wrong with [contentOffset](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/contentOffset).

Also have a look on iOS7 automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets and edgesForExtendedLayout
You can [read more here](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/AppearanceCustomization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH15-SW1)